# Push Notification Down

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I have already published apps using notification and since today (and maybe tomorrow) it stops working and I can't create new link (for new apps) using :

```
pushChannel = New HttpNotificationChannel(channelName)

' Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
AddHandler pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated, AddressOf PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated
AddHandler pushChannel.ErrorOccurred, AddressOf PushChannel_ErrorOccurred

pushChannel.Open()

' Bind this new channel for Tile events.
If Not pushChannel.IsShellToastBound Then
    pushChannel.BindToShellToast()
End If
If Not pushChannel.IsShellTileBound Then
    pushChannel.BindToShellTile()
End If
```

Is the server down? I don't use any certificate. Did it became necessary?

It return "time out" to send a notification or open a new channel!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have enough usage volume to have this problem, but you can only push 500 notifications per day per Subscription. if you want to go over that, you'll Need to set up an authenticated web service.
See these for more:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558(v=vs.92).

And

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941099(v=vs.92).aspx